# Prove $f(x)=1/x$ is Borel measurable

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

We note that $f(0)=+ \infty$. Need to evaluate $Y=\{x \in \mathbb R : f(x)>a \}$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

If $a>0$, then $Y=[0,1/a)$ (how is this equal to this?) is Borel.

If $a=0$, then $Y=[0,+\infty)$ (how is this equal to this?) is closed (how is this closed?), hence Borel.

If $a<0$, then $Y=(- \infty, 1/a) \cup [0, + \infty)$ (how is this equal to this?) is a union of two Borel sets hence Borel.

Comment: Seriously? How come you study measure theory, if you don't know how to solve $\frac1x>a$ ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It is knowing what to actually solve that is the confusing thing for me, jeez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a > 0$, then $x \in Y$ iff $f(x) > a$ iff $\frac{1}{x} > a$, and the latter happens for $x=0$, as $+\infty > a$ for any $a$, while negative $x$ yield negative $f(x)$, so they don't qualify (cannot be greater than a positive number). And if $x > 0$, then $\frac{1}{x} > a$ is equivalent to $1 > ax$ (multiplying by $x >0$ preserves order) and so to $x < \frac{1}{a}$ (divide by $a>0$). Hence $Y = [0, \frac{1}{a})$ which is Borel (intersection of closed and open set, say).

That for $a=0$ we get $Y = [0,+\infty)$ is similar (easier in fact), and this is is not closed in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, but *is* closed in the reals. It is Borel in either.

The last one is also not too hard: the left part are the $x < 0$ such that $\frac{1}{x} > a$, now multiplying by $x$ or dividing by $a$ reverse the sign, so you have to adapt the argument a bit. And if $x=0$, then $f(x) = +\infty > a$ and if $x > 0$, then $\frac{1}{x} > 0 > a$ as well. So all those $x$ are in $Y$ as well.